# Prove that $f: \Bbb R \setminus \{2 \} \to \Bbb R \setminus \{3 \}$ is bijective

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I wanna know how can I have a formal proof for this one 
$$f: \Bbb R \setminus \{2 \} \to \Bbb R \setminus \{3 \}.$$
I understand that for functions like this $f(x)=2x+1$. I can know if its is injective and surjective by saying that:

For injectivity:
\begin{align}f(a)&=f(b)\\
2a+1&=2b+1\\
2a&=2b\\
a&=b
\end{align}
∴ injective.

For surjectivity:
Let $r$ be an element of $\Bbb R$
\begin{align}
2x+1&=r\\
2x&=r-1\\
x&=(r-1)/2
\end{align}
∴ surjective

∴ bijective (since it is both injective and surjective)

Now i wanna know how to have a formal proof for the first function I mentioned. Hope someone can help me :) thanks.

Comment: Do you want to find a bijective $f:\mathbb{R}-\{2\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}-\{3\}$?

Comment: yes I that's what I mean.

Comment: would $f(x)=x+1$ be the one? :-)

Comment: What I mean is that I wanna prove that f:R∖{2}→R∖{3} is bijective.

Comment: Easiest way in this case is to write down an explicit inverse function :).

Comment: and what function could that be? :)

Comment: Take @QuangHoang's function and write down the inverse of that function...in other words, when you add one to $x$, what should you do to get $x$ back?

Comment: haha i don't get it.

Comment: haha wait i just got the idea why f(x)=x+1 is the function. thanks :)

Comment: @echizen12 simply saying $f : \mathbb{R} \setminus \{2\} \to \mathbb{R} \setminus \{3\}$ is not enough to define a function. For instance I could have $f : \mathbb{R} \setminus \{2\} \to \mathbb{R} \setminus \{3\}, x \mapsto -1$ and this is a possibility for what you're talking about.